# Converting Character and CodePoint in Swift

Tags: string, swift

Can I convert directly between a Swift Character and its Unicode numeric value? That is:

```
var i:Int = ...  // A plain integer index.
var myCodeUnit:UInt16 = myString.utf16[i]
// Would like to say myChar = myCodeUnit as Character, or equivalent.
```

or...

```
var j:String.Index = ... // NOT an integer!
var myChar:Character = myString[j]
// Would like to say myCodeUnit = myChar as UInt16
```

I **can** say:

```
myCodeUnit = String(myChar).utf16[0]
```

but this means creating a new String for each character. And I am doing this thousands of times (parsing text) so that is a **lot** of new Strings that are immediately being discarded.

Comment: Be aware that unicode is not a 16-bit charset, but a 21bit charset.

Comment: Can you do this operation in bulk? Say read a `String` of 1024 characters, then `for in` loop through each character instead of allocating a `String` per character?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the 21-bit issue. It is even more complicate than that, alas. Thanks SiLo, that is what I am doing. In fact, I keep an integer index and a String.Index going in parallel. But it seems a bit roundabout.

Answer (score 4):

The type `Character` represents a "Unicode grapheme cluster", which can be multiple Unicode codepoints. If you want one Unicode codepoint, you should use the type `UnicodeScalar` instead.

Answer (score 4):

As per the swift book:

**String to Code Unit**

To get codeunit/ordinals for each character of the String, you can do the following:

```
var yourSwiftString = "甲乙丙丁"
for scalar in yourSwiftString.unicodeScalars {
    print("\(scalar.value) ")
}
```

**Code Unit to String**

Because swift current does not have a way to convert ordinals/code units back to UTF, the best way I found is to still NSString. i.e. if you have int ordinals (32bit but representing the 21bit codepoints) you can use the following to convert to Unicode:

```
var i = 22247
var unicode_str = NSString(bytes: &i, length: 4, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding)
```

Obviously if you want to convert a array of ints, you'll need to pack them into a array first.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to an Apple engineer who is working on Unicode and he says they have not completed the implementation of unicode characters in strings. Are you looking at getting a code unit or a full character? Because the only and proper way to get at a full unicode character is by using a for each loop on a string. ie

```
for c in "hello" {
    // c is a unicode character of type Character
}
```

But, this is not implemented as of yet.

Comment: Thank you Kyle, it looks like the for-in iteration is working. I can't use that as-is because I need to break out of the loop and then back in, resuming where I left off, hundreds of times (tokenizing). BUT.. I see there is support for generators! I haven't figured out how to use them yet (perhaps not completely implemented) but that will be the way I go when I go. I do want to do this completely in Swift, just for consistency's sake. Otherwise I would get an NSData object.