# Unicode and Acceptable Arguments for "\u{}"

Tags: swift, unicode

```
"\u{63}"
"\u{1FF}"
"\u{23E}"
```

all produce the desired result - various unicode characters, but **I can't get the function to accept a variable**.   I have tried defining variable types including INT, UINT and UINT8 without success.

I have looked at documentation and all over.  Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to insert the contents of a variable inside the string?

Comment: yes e.g. <br/> var j: UInt <br/> j = 63  <br/> "\u{j}"

Comment: The `\u{}` syntax is only for the compiler that reads the source file. No processing of this kind will or should happen if you generate a string with `\u{}` at runtime. If you already have a numeric value of a character in a variable, [create a char from that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24102208/11683) and append it to the string.

Comment: illuminating thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it dynamically, you can create `Character` instances from `UnicodeScalar` instances like this

```
Character(UnicodeScalar(0x63))  // c
Character(UnicodeScalar(0x1FF)) // ǿ
Character(UnicodeScalar(0x23E)) // Ⱦ
```

which could be easily wrapped into a function

```
func characterForUnicodeCodePoint(codePoint: UInt32) -> Character {
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(codePoint))
}
```